# Can you place SVG defs in the head tag of an HTML document?

Tags: html, svg

If you wanted to declare your SVG definitions globally can you define them in the header of the document or do you have to define them in body?

In the head:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <svg>
         <defs>
            <rect id="boxyBox" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#00F;"></rect>
            <rect id="circlyCircle" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#00F;"></rect>
         </defs> 
      </svg>
   </head>
   <body>
      <svg>
         <use xlink:href="#boxyBox"/>
         <use xlink:href="#circlyCircle"/>
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the body:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <svg>
         <defs>
            <rect id="boxyBox" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#00F;"></rect>
            <rect id="circlyCircle" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#00F;"></rect>
         </defs> 
      </svg>
      <svg>
         <use xlink:href="#boxyBox"/>
         <use xlink:href="#circlyCircle"/>
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXOqJo). It appears to work in both cases.

It appears in the codepen at least, that you have to set the position to absolute in either case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't place SVG images (or any other kind of image) in the head of an HTML document, so it follows that you can't place *any* SVG elements in the head of an HTML document.

I mean, you "can", the document isn't going to refuse to render since it's HTML, not XHTML, but the `svg` element containing the defs will just get moved into the body as a separate SVG image (which you might have observed if you've tested this yourself beforehand) and, needless to say, it's simply invalid markup. That said, in both examples you have two separate SVG images (which is the reason why you seemingly have to apply absolute positioning) and you can clearly see that one has no trouble referencing the defs in the other.

Comment: I don't see why it would be invalid. You can declare styles in the header or link externally. I don't see why SVG definitions would be any different. In fact you can link in external SVG files. I created a codepen. It works with definitions in the head or the body. How did you "observe" the defs getting moved to the body?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: SVG is not HTML. I observed it by inspecting the DOM.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer but why are you calling it images? I know you know that SVG is not an image it's a vector (scalable vector graphics). Unless you mean SVG resources such as bitmap fills?

Comment: @1.21 gigawatts: Because vectors and bitmaps (aka rasters) are both image formats. You also reference SVG files with the img element.

Comment: Would probably have been clearer to simply state that HTMLHeadElement (<head>) can only contain base,link,meta,noscript,script,style,template,and title elements.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts out of much curiosity, how do you link in the external svg in the head? Do you use `<link>` and if so, which `rel` attribute do you assign?

Comment: @Chri.s I'm not sure I follow. I put the code I used in my question at the top. I can probably post another example if this is not what you are asking about.

Comment: @Chri.s I'm actually putting them in the body now and not in the head.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Ah okay, thank you. I was just wondering how you managed to load the svg inside the `<head>` element

Answer (score 1):

You can base64 encode svg file directly into background url attribute of a tag:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.download-button {
  display: block;
  background: #33A700 url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,YOUR-BASE64-ENCODED-SVG-FILE==') no-repeat 3% 50%;
  background-size: 48px 48px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href='...' class='download-button'>My Download Button</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Or in the html body:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,YOUR-BASE64-ENCODED-SVG-FILE==" />
```